# Hyperthreading & Multi-core when compiling

Tags: linux-kernel

if I have a processor Pentium4 (Celeron-D) with "SMT (Hyperthreading) scheduler support" do I need to "Multi-core scheduler support" when compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you have an Intel Hyperthreaded CPU and you have HT enbaled in BIOS, you only need:

[ * ] Symmetric multi-processing support
 [ * ]   SMT (Hyperthreading) scheduler support

Comment: ACPI needs to be enabled as well